# To Edit Json_encoded string

Tags: php, html, preg-replace, json

As i'm new to php i have little idea about how to format json data using preg_replace.
I'm working on HTML5 charts and for that i'm fetching data from the database and encoding it using json_encode method.
Now my desired result would be :
     `[{label:"Apple",y:95},{label:"Robin",y:85},{label:"Ron",y:65},{label:"Roy",y:55},{lable:"Na",y:45}]`

While what i have is :     `{"data":[[{"lable":"Apple","y":95},{"lable":"Robin","y":85},{"lable":"Ron","y":65},{"lable":"Roy","y":55},{"lable":"Na","y":45}]]}`

What i have read is ill preg_replace method will be helpful but i dont know how. Please help. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to format JSON data or trying to modify its values?

Comment: format the json string that is being generated through the json_encode method

Comment: Try [`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-unescaped-slashes#constant.json-pretty-print) second parameter of json_encode.

Comment: please let me know if my question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that your json is not valid. say for example i had this:

```
[{"label":"Apple","y":"95"},{"label":"Apple","y":"95"},{"label":"Apple","y":"95"}]
```

Then i wanted to decode this with php:

```
$json_convert_to_array = json_decode($json, true);
```

it would look like this:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Apple
            [y] => 95
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Apple
            [y] => 95
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => Apple
            [y] => 95
        )

)
```

Then to edit a value and pack it back into json you can do this:

```
$json_convert_to_array[2]['label'] = "new Val";

print json_encode($json_convert_to_array);
```

should look like this now:

```
[{"label":"Apple","y":95},{"label":"Apple","y":95},{"label":"new Val","y":95}]
```

hope this helps.